# Java, can Boolean be assignedFrom boolean, and vice versa?

Tags: java, reflection

When I run this code fragment, neither side is taken.

```
if (Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(boolean.class)) {
     uLog.error("Boolean is => boolean");
}
if (boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)) {
     uLog.error("boolean is <= Boolean");
}
```

Specifically, I'm trying to test the paramter types using reflection:

```
Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
```

and I can't figure out the proper test for boolean parameters.

Comment: That's because the answer is "no" in both cases... I don't see what that has to do with getting the parameter types?

Comment: @mini, it was a trivial test case that I thought was what testing the Type did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of built-in `boolean` is represented by [`Boolean.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TYPE). Since `boolean` cannot be inherited, you do not need `isAssignableFrom`: you can simply check the type in question for equality to `Boolean.TYPE` to see if the type of a parameter is built-in `boolean`.

Answer (score 5):

`Boolean` (the object) and `boolean` (the primitive) cannot be cast/assigned to each other. However, since Java 1.5, the compiler will automatically box/unbox between the two.

When you do:

```
boolean b =
Boolean bb = b;
b = bb;
```

The Java compiler automatically converts it to:

```
boolean b=
Boolean bb = Boolean.valueOf(b);
b = bb.booleanValue();
```